# Sql server 2008 - server name changed

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

I have changed the computer name of the server where sql server 2008 r2 is installed. 
Old name is WIN-OUJEKRMGXXX and new server name is KASURDYYY
When i configure replication following error occurs:

```
SQL Server Replication requires actual server name to make a connection to the server ... Specify the actual server name, WIN-OUJEKRMGXXX
```

i updated the server name in sql server in order to resolve the issue. i run following queries

```
sp_dropserver WIN-OUJEKRMGXXX
sp_addserver KASURDYYY, local
```

but still same error occurs

i checked the server name :

```
select @@SERVERNAME returns value WIN-OUJEKRMGXXX
select SERVERPROPERTY('SERVERNAME') returns value KASURDYYY
```

need help.

Comment: Did you restart SQL Server or reboot the server after making the change?

Comment: yes i have restarted the server

Comment: Can you open a cmd prompt and type 'ver' and share the output?

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

Answer (score 0):

I don`t have any permissions yet to comment :(

I searched for more people with the same issue. 
And the only difference I see is that they put the information inside ''.

> sp_dropserver 'old_server_name' 
>   GO 
>   sp_addserver 'current_server_name','local'
>   GO

…and then restart SQL Server for the changes to take effect.